# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'music_controller.api'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When I run the server, I am getting the following error:

```
   from music_controller.api.models import Room
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'music_controller.api'
```

I think the problem is from the import in the `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializers import RoomSerializer
from .models import Room


# Create your views here.

class RoomView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Room.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RoomSerializer
```

I made sure that the app name is included in `INSTALLED_APPS` in the `settings.py`.

The following is the tree of my project:

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

In the music_controller directory, add a file called `__init__.py`. Leave the file empty.